# How to set the default value for INT parameter to NULL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure but would like the default value of a parameter to be NULL but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

The following returns 5 rows:

```
SELECT
[strEmployeeName]
FROM
tblEmployees
WHERE [fkDepartment] IS NULL
```

This returns nothing at all:

```
DECLARE @departmentID INT = NULL

SELECT
[strEmployeeName]
FROM
tblEmployees
WHERE [fkDepartment] =@departmentID
```

I am wondering what I need to do to get the same results as the first query from the second.

Comment: NULL is never equal to anything - that is a common misunderstanding. If your parameter can be null and you want to find rows based on that parameter matching a column, you will need two sets of conditions as indicated by karan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use condition as `([fkDepartment] IS NULL AND @departmentID IS NULL) OR [fkDepartment] = @departmentID`

```
DECLARE @departmentID INT = NULL

SELECT
[strEmployeeName]
FROM
tblEmployees
WHERE ([fkDepartment] IS NULL AND @departmentID IS NULL) OR [fkDepartment] = @departmentID
```